# cmd to loop through a directory and remove special characters from file names

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm looking for a command line script that can loop through all the files in a desired directory and replace any special characters in the file names with spaces. I'm stuck on the replace logic for the special characters. Looking to replace anything not in (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789 ).

```
for /r C:\yourdirectorypath %F in (*) do replace(filename, regexp, ' ')
```

Comment: _Special_ characters?  Which respect _special_ in? Please [edit] your question and provide a _complete_ list of them.

Comment: I added a list of the characters i wanted to keep. So anything other than those would need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Next `.bat` script could help. Commented with `::` or `rem` lines for better understanding.

I do not know a `regexp` support in `cmd`; hence, a particular string is parsed on a *character by character* basis in the `:convrt` subroutine (note false result if there is any `%` percent sign present in a string supplied to parse).

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions
:: all `echo` lines for debugging purposes only (remove no sooner than debugged)
:::: set "_ALLOWED=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.0123456789"
:::: set "_REPLWITH=-"
:: next setting suffice as '%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%' is case insensitive
set "_ALLOWED=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789-"
:: note a blank space in the above line (with no full stop)
:: note last character of %_ALLOWED% value used to be the replace one as follows
set "_REPLWITH=%_ALLOWED:~-1%"

:: a filename sample (no extension) to be converted 
:: containing some batch-exceptional characters
SET "_sample=AÄaá^ cč^DĎ(1!)&°~!.foo~bar"
call :convrt _ELPAMS _sample

:: next lines show an intentional usage (with no subfolder recursion)  
pushd "D:\bat\Unusual Names"
:: create a particular file of an unusual name: echo _sample "%_sample%">"%_sample%.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B "A*.txt"') do (
  echo(
  set "_sample=%%~nG"
  call :convrt _ELPAMS _sample
  call :output "for debugging purposes only"
)
popd

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

Next :convrt subroutine accepts two parameters (passed by reference):
  %1 (output) variable name
  %2 (input)  variable name
The subroutine will return 
 - any `~` tilde character unchanged "it's not a bug, it's a feature";
 - wrong result for any `%` percent sign present in a file name. 

:convrt
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "__auxAll=%~2"
call set "__auxAll=%%%~2%%"
echo sub %~2 "%__auxAll%"
set "__result="
:loop
  if "%__auxAll%"=="" goto :endconvrt
  set "__auxOne=%__auxAll:~0,1%"
  set "__auxAll=%__auxAll:~1%"
  call set "__changed=%%_ALLOWED:%__auxOne%=%%"
  if not "%__changed%"=="%_ALLOWED%" (
    set "__result=%__result%%__auxOne%"
  ) else (
    set "__result=%__result%%_REPLWITH%"
  )
goto :loop

:endconvrt
echo sub %~1 "%__result%"

ENDLOCAL&call set "%~1=%__result%"
goto :eof

:output
  rem echo for _sample "%_sample%"
  echo for _ELPAMS "%_ELPAMS%"
goto :eof
```

**Output** sample. Note the `%` case (a thoughtful patchwork):

```
==>D:\bat\SU\921338.bat
sub _sample "AÄaá^ cč^DĎ(1!)&°~!.foo~bar"
sub _ELPAMS "A-a-- c--D--1----~--foo~bar"

sub _sample "AÄaá^ cč^DĎ(1!)&°~!.foo~bar"
sub _ELPAMS "A-a-- c--D--1----~--foo~bar"
for _ELPAMS "A-a-- c--D--1----~--foo~bar"

sub _sample "AÄzž^ yýS%OS%Š%%OS%%(%1!)&°~%%G!^%~2.foo~bar"
sub _ELPAMS "A-z-- y-S%OS%-%%OS%%-%1----~%%G--%~2-foo~bar"
for _ELPAMS "A-z-- y-SWindows_NT-%OS%-_ELPAMS----~%G--_sample-foo~bar"
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`set "_REPLWITH=%_ALLOWED:~-1%"` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)